# How to enable tab bar transition animation to work without initial view controller

Tags: swift

Essentially I have the following custom transition animation for Tab Bar Controller:

**MyFadeTransition.swift**

```
import UIKit

class MyFadeTransition: NSObject, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning {
    func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
        if let fromVC = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .from), let toVC = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .to) {
            toVC.view.frame = fromVC.view.frame
            toVC.view.alpha = 0
            fromVC.view.alpha = 1
            transitionContext.containerView.addSubview(fromVC.view)
            transitionContext.containerView.addSubview(toVC.view)

            UIView.animate(withDuration: transitionDuration(using: transitionContext), animations: {
                toVC.view.alpha = 1
            }) { (finished) in
                transitionContext.completeTransition(finished)
            }
        }
    }

    func animationEnded(_ transitionCompleted: Bool) {
        // no-op
    }

    func transitionDuration(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> TimeInterval {
        return 0.12
    }
}
```

The issue is the code also requires the Tab Bar Controller to be the initial view controller during launch and the code below in the `AppDelegate`

```
let tab = window!.rootViewController as! UITabBarController
tab.delegate = self
```

The following must also be added to **AppDelegate.swift**

```
extension AppDelegate: UITabBarControllerDelegate {
    func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, animationControllerForTransitionFrom fromVC: UIViewController, to toVC: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        let fade = MyFadeTransition()

        return fade
    }
}
```

I am using a different ViewController as the Initial ViewController, how can I make the code continue to work without having it as the Initial Controller?

Comment: How do you configure `MyFadeTransition` in usage ? also `AppDelegate` part is relevant it only sets the delegate which has no relation to the animation

Comment: I just added some more details, Please have a look.

Comment: The extension is what makes the animation execute and work. I would like to be able to set a different view controller as the initial view controller and still have the animation work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to subclass `UITabBarController` and use

```
class CustomTab:UITabBarController,UITabBarControllerDelegate { 
   override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      self.delegate = self
   }
   func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, animationControllerForTransitionFrom fromVC: UIViewController, to toVC: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? { 
      return MyFadeTransition()
   }
}
```

Then assign `CustomTab` as class name to the tabBar in IB