# Need some help populating tableview with JSON data after POST request

Tags: json, swift, uitableview

Essentially I need to display JSON data in a tableview once a POST Request is made and the API responds with JSON.

I get no errors but I also don't get any JSON response that shows up in the debugger. I'm not sure what is wrong exactly but nothing seems to load or display in the tableview.

The following is the struct I am using to interpret the JSON:

```
import UIKit

struct ScheduleStructure: Codable {
    let customer: String
    let PickedUpNUM: String
    let DeliveryNUM: String

}
```

This is what the JSON should look like:

```
[
    {
        "customer": “Example”,
        "PickedUpNUM": “2”,
        "DeliveryNUM": “4”
    }
]
```

This is currently the tableview controller:

```
import UIKit



class ScheduleCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var cellStructure: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var testingCell: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var pickupLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var deliveryLabel: UILabel!
}

class ScheduleTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var driverName = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "name")!


    var structure = [ScheduleStructure]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false

        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white


        //Adds Shadow below navigation bar
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.masksToBounds = false
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 2.0)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.shadowRadius = 2


        self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true
        fetchJSON()
        let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
        refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(doSomething), for: .valueChanged)
        tableView.refreshControl = refreshControl

    }



    private func fetchJSON() {
        guard
            let url = URL(string: "https://example.com/example/example.php"),
            let value = driverName.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryValueAllowed)
            else { return }

        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.httpBody = "value=\(value)".data(using: .utf8)

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, _, error in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                //
            }
            }.resume()

    }

    @objc func doSomething(refreshControl: UIRefreshControl) {
        print("reloaded")

        fetchJSON()

    }



    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return structure.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customerID", for: indexPath) as! ScheduleCell



        cell.textLabel?.font = .boldSystemFont(ofSize: 18)
        cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.red

        let portfolio = structure[indexPath.row]

        cell.textLabel?.text = portfolio.customer


        return cell

    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {


        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customerID", for: indexPath) as! ScheduleCell
        //cell.cellStructure.layer.cornerRadius = 50
        let portfolio = structure[indexPath.row]


        let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: controller)

        self.present(navigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }


    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        fetchJSON()

    }



}
```

Please let me know if there is an entirely better way to do this

I just need to do a JSON POST and display the result in a table.

Comment: First, you must check if you really can get the response data, and print it on console.

Comment: start property names with small letter and use `enum CodingKeys` to accomplish that or change the the returned response

Comment: Got it, thank you. You're response really helped me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to decode the json response as array inside the callback to the api

```
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, _, error in 
       guard let data = data else { return }
       do {
         self.structure = try JSONDecoder().decode([ScheduleStructure].self,from:data)
          DispatchQueue.main.async {
           self.tableView.reloadData()
          }
        }
        catch {
          print(error)
        } 

}.resume()
```

---

```
struct ScheduleStructure: Codable {
    let customer, pickedUpNUM, deliveryNUM: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case customer
        case pickedUpNUM = "PickedUpNUM"
        case deliveryNUM = "DeliveryNUM"
    }
}
```

Comment: If possible can you please take a look at the following question I also had: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56471085/how-to-enable-tab-bar-transition-animation-to-work-without-initial-view-controll

Comment: Please let me know if you have any questions

Comment: Are you able to take a look at it?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are aware that the body of your `dataTask` is not actually doing anything with the data it receives? There is just an empty comment in there.

I'd guess you would want to do something like this:

```swift
if let data = data {
    do {
        self.structure = try JSONDecoder().decode(Array<ScheduleStructure>.self, from: data)
        self.reloadData()
    } catch {
        print("TODO: handle parse error: \(error)")
    }
} else {
    print("TODO: handle network error: \(error)")
}
```